# Mailing list member received unexpected opt-out message

Tags: civimail

Using CiviCRM 4.3.4 (update necessary, I know) one of our mailing list members has received an opt-out message, that he was unsubscribed from all mailing lists. In fact this is not true. He is still member of all those groups and has never been removed. Now I'm wondering why he received this e-mail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In civi, you have two ways to be removed from a mailing: unsubscribe from the group or opt-out (from any mailing).

The later doesn't remove the contact from any group, but change the status of the email and automatically exclude the contact from any mass mailing.

When you do to the contact summary, do you have a red icon next to his/her email?

If you want to have the contact receive mass mailing again, you need to edit the contact and uncheck the opt-out (beware, you should only do that for contacts that actually want to receive emails)

As for why she/he was opted out, it's likely the email was forwarded around, and one of the recipient that received the forwarded email clicked on unsubscribe. Obviously, instead of preventing friends to forward you emails, it did unsubscribe the original recipient, hence the opt-out message.

Comment: Yes, you are right. According to the change log no one else has changed his settings. So he might have opt-out himself unconsciously. But shouldn't this has been logged too?

Comment: probably email forwarded around. I updated the answer, hope it makes sense

Comment: This could be a possible scenario, indeed. Thanks.

Comment: A hard bounce also sets the same flag. But I don't think it would generate the opt-out email.